# /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: java, hadoop

I enter this command and the it gives back this error

> `bin/hadoop jar
>   share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar grep input
>   output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
>
> bin/hadoop: line 144: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin/bin/java: No
>   such file or directory`

please help.

Comment: The error message is very clear.. Looks like Java cannot be found in the path that Hadoop expects it to be.

Comment: might be the double 'bin/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to set Hadoop. You should find where Java is installed in your machine, then go to

```
/etc/<hadoop>/<conf>/hadoop-env.sh
```

and change `JAVA_HOME` to where Java is installed.

In order to know where Java is installed, try to `echo $JAVA_HOME` (if it's set it'll show the path), if not, try to search for it:

```
sudo find /usr/ -name *jdk
```

---

Now I've noticed that you have a double `/bin` in the path, change the `JAVA_HOME` and remove the redundant `/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Path `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin/bin/java` has `/bin/bin` twice. It shows that `PATH` environment or `JAVA_HOME` variable is wrongly configured. Check that path specified in `PATH` variable should be `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin` or `JAVA_HOME = /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre`